# Solving an expression based on an equation

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving

I would like to know if there's an efficient way to solve an expression based on an equation? For example, I have the equation:

> $x^3+4x-8=0$

and the expression:

> $x^7+64x^2$

which i have to find the value of.

Apparently that equation can't be solved using some common method, so i have to play a bit with the expression by squaring both sides and adding some numbers and so.

My question here is: is there an efficient method to solve these questions without guessing the steps of solution luckily ?

Comment: Long division of polynomials: divide $x^7+64x^2$ by $x^3+4x-8$ and record the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, long division of polynomials works: $${x^7+64x^2}=({x^3+4x-8})\cdot p(x)+r(x)$$

First factor out $\color{red}{x^4}$, so you are left with $$(x^7+64x^2)-(x^7+4x^5-8x^4)=-4x^5+8x^4+64x^2$$

Then factor out $\color{red}{-4x^2}$, so you are left with $$(-4x^5+8x^4+64x^2)-(-4x^5-16x^3+32x^2)=8x^4+16x^3+32x^2$$

Then factor out $\color{red}{8x}$, so you are left with $$(8x^4+16x^3+32x^2)-(8x^4+32x^2-64x)=16x^3+64x$$

Finally factor out $\color{red}{16}$,  so you are left with $$(16x^3+64x)-(16x^3+64x-128)=128$$
So you have that $${x^7+64x^2}=({x^3+4x-8})\color{red}{\underbrace{(x^4-4x^2+8x+16)}_{\text{the factors}}}+128$$So when $x$ is such that $x^3+4x-8=0$, you have that $x^7+64x^2=128$.

Comment: Thanks, so it's all about using polynomials long division and making the denominator equal to zero to acquire the remainder alone as a result. I'm curious about something though, would i use the same method if the degree of the "equation" is more than the degree of the expression? Like here, it will be : x^3+4x+ 8 = (x^7+64 - r(x))/p(x)

Comment: @StephenAlexander Then you can divide the other way, and be left with something like $$\text{expression}=\frac{\text{equation}}{\text{factor}}+r(x)$$ The key is to get the $\text{equation}$ in the numerator of something, and get the $\text{expression}$ as a separate term, so that when the equation is $0$, you have just $$\text{expression}=r(x)$$ where, if you're lucky, $r(x)$ is just a number, and so you have an answer. Notice that this problem is set up in a way that $r(x)$ is a number, but in general this would not be the case, and you may have $x$'s in there which would complicate things.